# How to Save Changes in existing Excel File on C# without re saving the file?

Tags: c#, excel

```
worksheet.Cells[1,2] = "MSC"; //Editing the file
        worksheet.Cells[1,1].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        theWorkbook.Save(); //Saving The file it throws Read only file Exception
```

when i use this piece of code an exception occurs telling me that the file is read only and i have to save a new copy from it
and if i use

```
theWorkbook.Close(misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

it pop up a message window to save a new copy from the file and i want to edit the file and save it to the existing file

Answer (score 1):

The post found [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/196171/884992#post884992) provides code to save the workbook in a temporary file and overwrites the original file with that temporary copy.

Relevant snippet:

```csharp
//[...]
string tmpName = Path.GetTempFileName();
File.Delete(tmpName);        
wb.SaveAs(tmpName, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
wb.Close(false, missing, missing);
excel.Quit();
File.Delete(Fname);
File.Move(tmpName, Fname);
```